# keras custom layer K.reshape could not broadcast input array from shape (15,4) into shape (1,4)

Tags: python-3.x, keras

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
import keras.engine as KE
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
inputs = Input(shape = [3,5,4])
class GetBox(KE.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GetBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, inputs):
        out_boxes = K.reshape(inputs, [-1, 4])
        return out_boxes
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (None, 4) 
mmoutputs = GetBox()(inputs)
model = Model(inputs, mmoutputs)
print(model.output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
a = np.zeros([1,3,5,4])
model.predict(a, batch_size = 1, verbose = 0)
```

**Error**

```
error: ValueError                                Traceback (most
recent call last) <ipython-input-19-6d37dae515cd> in <module>()
     26 a = np.zeros([1,3,5,4])
     27 
---> 28 model.predict(a, batch_size = 1, verbose = 0)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps)    1833         f =
self.predict_function    1834         return self._predict_loop(f,
ins, batch_size=batch_size,
-> 1835                                   verbose=verbose, steps=steps)    1836     1837     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
_predict_loop(self, f, ins, batch_size, verbose, steps)    1337                         outs.append(np.zeros(shape, dtype=batch_out.dtype))    1338         
for i, batch_out in enumerate(batch_outs):
-> 1339                     outs[i][batch_start:batch_end] = batch_out    1340                 if verbose == 1:    1341          
progbar.update(batch_end)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (15,4) into
shape (1,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, keras's `Model.predict` expects an output of the same shape of zero axis, as the input has. I.e. you can't use a model's input with number of samples = 1 and convert it to the prediction of the shape 15, in your case.

This is a `model.summary()` output:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 3, 5, 4)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
get_box_1 (GetBox)           (None, 4)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

`Model.predict` tries to keep the number of samples in the output equals one (number of samples in input), but gets 15 samples and can't process it, so the following error occurs:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (15,4) into
shape (1,4)
```

I suppose, a shape of outs[i] equals (1,4), and you can't change it, because it's internal keras code:

```
outs[i][batch_start:batch_end] = batch_out
```

So, you should reshape the input of th model before you pass it to `model.predict`, or use this layer as internal layer and reshape it's output before an output layer of the model. For example, reshape output to the (1, 15, 4) with another layer. But solution  depends on  purpose of your code, which is unclear for me now. Would you explain your goal? Depends on this, may be you need just tensorflow code or so.